# reading in tiff files and matching them based on name

Tags: r, directory, raster, directory-structure, terra

I am using R 4.2.0 and am trying to read a series on tif files nested in different folders. My folder set up is as follows:

scenario 1/ global_model/ high_level/

```
         scenario1_highlevel_2020.tif
         scenario1_highlevel_2030.tif
         scenario1_highlevel_2040.tif
```

scenario 1/ global_model/nested/

```
         scenario1_nested_2020.tif
         scenario1_nested_2030.tif
         scenario1_nested_2040.tif
```

scenario 2/ global_model/ high_level/

```
         scenario2_highlevel_2020.tif
         scenario2_highlevel_2030.tif
         scenario2_highlevel_2040.tif
```

scenario 2/ global_model/nested/

```
         scenario2_nested_2020.tif
         scenario2_nested_2030.tif
         scenario2_nested_2040.tif
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is to merge the nested and highlevel tifs from each scenario and each year. For example, I am trying to merge *scenario1_highlevel_2020.tif* and *scenario2_nested_2020.tif*. I have all the necessary code to merge each one individually but I am running into issues how to loop through each scenario folder.

What I would like to do is loop through scenario 1 folder, read in *scenario1_highlevel_2020.tif*
and *scenario1_highlevel_2020.tif* and then merge them, then go onto read in *scenario1_highlevel_2030.tif*
and *scenario1_highlevel_2030.tif*  and merge those, and then read in *scenario1_highlevel_2030.tif*
and *scenario1_highlevel_2030.tif* and merge those. Then I want to loop through scenario 2 and do the same.

```
# What I am thinking right now (in English code)
for each tif in scenario1/global_model/nested {
     read in tif
} # this would give me 3 tiffs, nested_2020, nested_2030, nested_2040

for each tif in scenario 1/global_model/high level {
     read in tif
} #this would give me 3 tiffs, highlevel_2020, highlevel_2030, highlevel_2040

for each tif in (2020,2030,2040) {
     use function I created to merge the tifs}
```

Then I need to do the same for scenario 2, which could probably be done earlier in the code?

Im fairly new to R/ havent used it a few years so please let me know if you have any ideas of how to do this!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Try looking into `terra` or  the `raster` packages and add these two tags to your question, so that relevant people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two nested loops to do that, one to loop over the scenarios folders and another one to cycle over the years of interest. Then, you can use `list.files` to search for files that meet certain pattern. Something similar to the following should work:

```
library(raster)

folders <- c("scenario 1","scenario 2")

years <- c(2020, 2030, 2040)

resul <- lapply(folders, function(folder){
  lapply(years, function(year){
    high <- list.files(paste0(folder,"/", "global_model/high_level/"),
                       "*",year,".tif",
                       full.names = T)
    nested <- list.files(paste0(folder,"/", "global_model/nested/"),
                         "*",year,".tif",
                         full.names = T)
    high <- stack(high)
    nested <- stack(nested)
    
    stack(high, nested)
  })
})
```